# Selecting the previous hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small web form with a repeating section, and I have a checkbox that I want to effect the previous hidden field like so:

```
<td>
    <label class="lblappUploadRequired" style="display: none"></label>
    <input type="hidden" class="data" name="Approvals[0].appUploadRequired" value="false"/>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="changeUpReq()" />
</td>
function changeUpReq() {
        alert($(this).prev().attr('name'));
        $(this).prev().val(this.checked ? 'true' : 'false');
    }
```

But all I get is Undefined in my alert and the value is not set.  Am I messing something here?

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers.

Comment: @j08691  could you expound on that?  If you mean the code shouldn't be on each line, that's true, it's in a separate JS file, it's just here for example purposes.

Comment: @Herrozerro He didn't mean that. He said, Instead of writing `onclick='something()'` in your html. You could bind events for them by using `.addEventListener`/`$().click(...)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy No, they meant exactly what they said. Using inline events (those that are attached in an HTML element) is a bad idea cause you are mixing mark-up with code. Your code is more maintainable in separate files (html, css & script) having to find every call to a method in an HTML file is a pain in the neck. However, modifying one method that binds all the events is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to receive the `this` in your event handler,

JS:

```
function changeUpReq(_this) {
   alert($(_this).prev().attr('name'));
   $(_this).prev().val(_this.checked ? 'true' : 'false');
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="changeUpReq(this)" />
```

This may fix your issue. But it would be better to go with creating a dedicated event handler for it.

Comment: @Herrozerro Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

in `function changeUpReq()` what do you expect `$(this)` to be? 
maybe change it to a selector?

```
    $("input").on('click', function(el){
      alert($(this).prev().attr('name'));
      $(this).prev().val(this.checked ? 'true' : 'false');
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I had assumed this was the sender, but I see that is wrong.

Comment: It can be passed, I think, but then you need to accept a parameter in your function. but anyway it's a better practice to separate the js from the html and just use the on('click') event listener.